# Powershell - How To Filter Output

Tags: powershell

I need assistance in filtering what is going in to my output.
Here is my code:

```
$FolderPath = Get-ChildItem -Directory -Path "Z:\D482\F11\SECURE" -Recurse -Force 
$Output = @()
ForEach ($Folder in $FolderPath) {
    $Acl = Get-Acl -Path $Folder.FullName
    ForEach ($Access in $Acl.Access) {
        $Properties = [ordered]@{'Folder Name'=$Folder.FullName;'Group/User'=$Access.IdentityReference  }
        $Output += New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property $Properties            
    }
}
$Output  | ConvertTo-Csv | Out-File C:\Temp\Secured.txt
```

My output looks like this:

```text
#TYPE System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject
"Folder Name","Group/User"
"Z:\D482\F11\SECURE\QA\CDM\To_Load\Duals\Load_Completed","S-1-5-21-1275210071-879983540-1801674531-105509"
"Z:\D482\F11\SECURE\QA\Files\CDM\To_Load\Duals\Load_Completed","S-1-5-21-1275210071-879983540-1801674531-121910"
"Z\D482\F11\SECURE\QA\D482\To_Load\Duals\Load_Completed","DOMAIN\CXL3708"
```

In my output, I only want lines that contain our domain name ( as illustrated by the line with DOMAIN in it.

I have not been successful - either I get nothing, or I get error messages in the console.

Comment: What errors did you get with Where-Object?

Comment: [1] why use `ConvertTo-Csv` with `Out-File` instead of `Export-Csv`? [2] you can get rid of the typeinfo stuff by using the `-NoTypeInformation` parameter. [3] i don't see ANY filtering ... have you tried `Where-Object` in your final pipeline?

Answer (score 2):

here is one way to do the job ... [*grin*]

what it does ...

- sets the constants
- builds a parameter splat for the `Get-ChildItem` call
- grabs the dirs from the source path
- iterates thru the dir list
- gets the acl list for the current dir & filters for those that start with the required domain name
  note that i don't have a `.IdentityReference` property in my ACL, so i used `.Owner` instead.
- iterates thru those acl items
- builds a `[PSCustomObject]` for the current acl
- sends that out to the `$AccessInfo` collection
- displays the content of the above on screen
- saves the collection to a csv file

the code ...

```
$SourcePath = $env:TEMP
$DomainName = $env:USERDOMAIN
$ReportFile = "SO_Erich_Powershell - How To Filter Output.csv"
$FullReportFile = Join-Path -Path $env:TEMP -ChildPath $ReportFile

$GCI_Params = @{
    LiteralPath = $SourcePath
    Directory = $True
    Force = $True
    Recurse = $True
    ErrorAction = 'SilentlyContinue'
    }
$DirList = Get-ChildItem @GCI_Params

$AccessInfo = foreach ($DL_Item in $DirList)
    {
    $AclList = Get-Acl -LiteralPath $DL_Item.FullName |
        Where-Object {
            $_.Owner -match "^$DomainName"
            }
    foreach ($AL_Item in $AclList)
        {
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            DirName = $DL_Item.FullName
            # my single system has no ".IdentityReference" property
            #    so i used ".Owner"
            GroupOrUser = $AL_Item.Owner
            }
        }
    }

# display the data
$AccessInfo

# send to a csv file
$AccessInfo |
    Export-Csv -LiteralPath $FullReportFile -NoTypeInformation
```

truncated screen output ...

```
DirName                             GroupOrUser     
-------                             -----------     
C:\Temp\1                           MySysName\AnotherUserName
C:\Temp\2                           MySysName\AnotherUserName
C:\Temp\3                           MySysName\AnotherUserName

[*snip ...*]

C:\Temp\vscode-update-system-x64    MySysName\MyUserName   
C:\Temp\WPF                         MySysName\MyUserName   
C:\Temp\mbam\qt-jl-icons            MySysName\MyUserName
```

truncated csv file content ...

```
"DirName","GroupOrUser"
"C:\Temp\1","MySysName\AnotherUserName"
"C:\Temp\2","MySysName\AnotherUserName"

[*snip ...*]

"C:\Temp\WPF","MySysName\MyUserName"
"C:\Temp\mbam\qt-jl-icons","MySysName\MyUserName"
```